# MVC Area with same name as controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Trying to set up an MVC route (im using MVC5) that will allow me to do the following:

- Thing/Index
- Thing/Create
- Thing/Reports/Index
- Thing/Reports/SomeReport

As such, in the default 'area' (i.e. no area), i've added a 'Thing' controller.
In my 'Thing' controller i have 'Index' and 'Create'actions.

I've then added a 'Thing' area. I've added a 'Reports' controller to this area, and in this controller i've added 'Index' and 'SomeReport' actions.

Within my global - i'm calling:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

The routes are defined as follows;

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Thing_default",
    "Thing/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "MyApplication.Areas.Thing.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "MyApplication.Controllers" }
);
```

With this configuration i get the following results;

- Thing/ - OK
- Thing/Index - 404
- Thing/Create - 404
- Thing/Reports - OK
- Thing/Reports/Index - OK
- Thing/Reports/SomeReport - OK

I've tried the same kind of thing with Attribute Routing - but again, have had no success.

Can anyone elaborate on how I can achieve this? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Thing/Index` means you calling the `Index()` method of `IndexController` in `Thing` area (which does not exist)

Comment: Yes, I understand why it isn't working. Trying to work out how I can configure it, so that it will work.

Comment: You would need to create specific routes for `Thing/Index` and `Thing/Create` (and they need to be before other routes) - e.g. `url: "Thing/Index" defaults: { controller = "Thing", action = "Index" }`

Comment: Ok. That kinda sucks :( 
In which case - i may as well just have an attribute route on every single action.

Comment: Or just change the name of the `area` so its not the same as a the controller :)

Comment: Which is what i didn't want to do haha. I might consider reversing it. i.e. Reports/Thing/{action}

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me :)

Comment: did you ever find a better solution?